# Question re voltage gain glitch LTSpice simple one BJT amp simulation

Tags: amplifier, ltspice, gain, glitch

[image]

Screenshot shows a simple one BJT amplifier circuit in LTSpice, 100mV 800 Hz sinewave input with the output shown in the blue trace.
The green trace shows the calculated voltage gain i.e. Vout/Vin. This averages about -10 which is what I would have expected. I can't explain the reason for the glitches in the gain in 2 places: where the Vout passes through zero volts on the way up and, to a lesser extent, on the way down.
*(Sorry: I just noticed the names on the wires which I should have removed! Please ignore)*

Comment: To plot the voltage gain use the AC analysis instead of a transient one.

Comment: ^ Also, if there is no load `C4` is useless.

Comment: User, place a 10 Meg at the output just to provide a DC path. Also, increase your capacitor values by a factor of 33\$\times\$, let's say. See what happens then.

Answer (score 4):

> *I can't explain the reason for the glitches in the gain in 2 places:
> where the Vout passes through zero volts on the way up and, to a
> lesser extent, on the way down.*

The **v(Vout) / v(Vin)** relationship would be a straight line if the phase angle between them was bang-on 180° or bang-on 0°. But, because they can't be (maybe a fraction of a degree difference), you will have a potential **X** divided by **0** scenario and that will create these artefacts.

The node names are cool.

Comment: If you're looking for distortion, perform a FFT. You may need to turn off compression (Tools > Control Panel > Compression), set .options numdgt=7 plotwinsize=0, and perhaps decrease the step size in the .tran card.

Comment: @qrk can you explain why you have sent this comment to me?

Comment: Comment is for the OP, not you. Sorry about the confusion.